# Inserting data into additional attributes in pivot table

Tags: php, laravel

I have a tables `peoples` `countries` and a pivot table `country_people`. The pivot tables has got attributes `countries_id` `peoples_id` `number`. I am able to get the foreign keys into the pivot table but i can't insert into number. How do i do this ?

**People model**

```
 public function countries()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Country')->withPivot('number')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

**Country model**

```
public function peoples()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\People')->withPivot('number')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

**Controller**

```
   $people = new People(array(
        'quantity' => $request->get('quantity'),

    ));

    $people->save();
    $order->countries()->sync($request->get('id')->attach('quantity'));
```

Comment: `''quantity'` you have a typo here BTW, is that in your application?

Comment: @AndyHolmes, no that isn't in my application. Probably when i was trying to clean the code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're combining update methods. Check out https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships for more details.

In your case, try:

```
$order->countries()->attach($request->get('id'), ['number' =>
$peoples['quantity']);
```

If you want to sync, instead of attach, use:

```
$order->countries()->sync([$request->get('id') => ['number' =>
$peoples['quantity']]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to attach additional columns to the pivot table, you can pass it in through as array. For example:

```
$id = intval($request->get('id'));        
$order->countries()->sync( $id => ['number' => $quantity]);  //assuming you have saved the value of number in quantity
```

Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships under syncing associations for more details.

Also, keep in mind that using sync will remove any of the previous relationships if they are not specified in the array. Use syncWithoutDetaching if you don't want this to happen.